# {categories} tag pair not parsing contents

Tags: channel-entries, categories, cache, ce-cache

I'm trying to clear ce_cache of a category given a specific entry's set of categories. This doesn't seem to work and I think it's because the `{categories}` tag pair isn't quite a full implementation of the `parse_variables()` function. Any thoughts on how to accomplish the following?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel" 
    sort="desc" 
    orderby="entry_date"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="1"
    offset="1"
    disable="category_fields|custom_fields|member_data"}

    {categories}
    {exp:ce_cache:clear items="local/category/{category_url_title}" refresh="1"}
    {/categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a parse order issue. If so, using [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) should work to save the categories into a variable list, and then you can run the ce_cache:clear when outputting the list (this is untested):

```
{!--   cache a list of the category url titles   --}
{exp:stash:set_list 
    name="cached_cat_url_title" 
    parse_tags="yes"
    trim="yes"  
}
    {categories}
        {stash:cat_url_title}{category_url_title}{/stash:cat_url_title}
    {/categories}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!--   output the list of category url titles, breaking the cache for each one   --}
{exp:stash:get_list 
    name="cached_cat_url_title"
    parse_tags="yes"
    process="end"
}   
    {exp:ce_cache:clear items="local/category/{cat_url_title}" refresh="1"}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```